# Using XRDP to connect linux to Windows PC from LINUX Client

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, rdp, freerdp

Has anyone successfully used XRDP/freeRDP to remote login to a Windows PC from a LINUX Client?  I did some research on the matter and I found there may be incompatibility issues.  However those posts were quite old.

I would like to use the latest XRDP or freeRDP

The site says the following: 
"The goal of this project is to provide a fully functional Linux terminal server, capable of accepting connections from rdesktop, freerdp, and Microsoft's own terminal server / remote desktop clients.

Unlike Windows NT/2000/2003/2008/2012 server, xrdp will not display a Windows desktop but an X window desktop to the user.

So it sounds like I can communicate between a Linux Box and Windows.  But it sounds like the Windows PC can only be the client logging into a Linux Server and not vice-versa."

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true. You can using a freeRDP client in Linux connecting to a server on Windows. I've just tried the latest freeRDP code in Ubuntu, and I've tested Win7/Win10, both are OK.

Follow the instruction of freeRDP in the following link:
https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation
and hope you make it.

Ps: There may be some connectivity issues, like firewall or something, just google it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will try the same combination and see if it works for me.